# RXJS: How to combine into an array multiple HTTP Requests that returns an object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Hi I have a method that returns an `object`, I plan to call `n` number of times and `combine` into an `array` after making the last successful call.

```
  public getActivity({minprice, maxprice, type}: QueryParams) {
    const url = `${BASE_URL}?minprice=${minprice}&maxprice=${maxprice}&type=${type}`;
    return this.httpClient.get(url);
  }
```

I'm not really sure on how to do it in rxjs but my expected output would be like this:

```
activities = [{
  fetchedItemId: 1
},
{
  fetchedItemId: 2
},
{
  fetchedItemId: 3
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  getActivity() {
    from(new Array(5))
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(() => this.appService.getActivity(this.filter)),
      filter((activity: Activity) => !activity.error),
      toArray(),
    )
    .subscribe((activities: Activity[]) => {
      this.activities = activities;
    });
  }
```

I managed to solve it with a combination of pipe, mergeMap, filter and toArray